# How to access a method from one dart file to another?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have created this method in another dart file and i have to access it in main dart file. I don't know how to access this as it only belongs to that class. I am a beginner in flutter and firebase(as shown below is firebase code).

`````
 DocumentReference db = Firestore.instance.collection('todolist').document(taskName);
 db.delete().whenComplete(() {
   print ('object deleted');
 });
}  ````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a library out of your first file:

```
library firestore_utils;

void deleteObject(){
 DocumentReference db = Firestore.instance.collection('todolist').document(taskName);
 db.delete().whenComplete(() {
   print ('object deleted');
 });
}
```

Now you should be able to import the lib inside an other file and use the function deleteObject(). Note that functions are invisible outside a lib or class if their name starts with "_", f. e "_deleteObject()"

Comment: This is so amazing answer, directly focused on beginners like me. Thank you for your useful time. As I am a beginner can you please suggest me some useful courses or ways to learn flutter and be good at it. It would be so helpful. Thank You.

Comment: Hi, glad I could help. One of the things that is really cool about Flutter is the documentary, which is really detailed. 
There you will also find tutorials for beginners: https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/tutorials
Have fun :)